# Excel - complex cascading dropdown filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to do a rather complex cascading filtering with multiple dropdown cells.

Ex:

```
A  1

A  2

A  3

B  1

B  2

B  3
```

There are still another colunm  A 1 has five more options. I would appreciate any help. Even if just a general direction. 
I have seen tutorials for only for non-repetitive cells like above. 
I would have:

```
A  1  z

A  1  y

A  1  w
```

and so forth.

Comment: What do you mean with non-repetitive cells? Can you edit your example and make it a bit clearer what you want to achieve? If user selects A in first dropdown, then they should see `1,2,3` as options in second dropdown. Is that correct? Where does `z,y,w` feature? is that a third dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you are after is dependent data validation. This can be achieved by arranging the data for the different drop-downs in named ranges and using Indirect to call the dependent range. Examples and full tutorial can be found at Deb Dalgleish's www.Contextures.com site [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)

Answer (score 0):

So after two days...
I found this [tutorial](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/07/17/create-dependent-drop-down-lists-containing-unique-distinct-values-in-excel/) . It brings the repetitive items. 
That is 50%. Basically, there are two lists.

a)a list with no repetitive terms. In the case above.

```
    A
    B
```

b) Then you have a list with all repetitive cells:

```
A
A
A
B
B
etc.
```

Need to create the Index()  and offset () as described in the tutorial above;

c) Then you have your dropdown cells reflecting "a", NOT 'b':

d) I used =CONCATENATE(cell, cell, etc)
Now you will have something like this
A1street (3 columns, "A:, "1", "street").

Use [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-text-from-two-or-more-cells-into-one-cell-81ba0946-ce78-42ed-b3c3-21340eb164a6) to create a table with concatenated terms. 
Add your *last column* (the result needed after choosing 2, 3 etc dropdowns) to the right of the concatenated values. 
In my case, ex,

```
A1street   $10,45
```

d) finally you use the lookup function to match the concatenated terms (as you use the dropdowns) with a specific cell showing the concatenated cells and compare with your new table.